java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine
I got the below error when starting the spring application :
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine tried to access protected method 'void org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler$AbstractContainer.<init>()' (org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine and org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler$AbstractContainer are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

The below is the pom file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <artifactId>aib</artifactId>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <description>Alizz Islamic Bank Integration</description>

    <properties>
        <revision>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</revision>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <cxf.version>4.0.4</cxf.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.0</jacoco.version>
        <jacoco.coverageRatio>0.85</jacoco.coverageRatio>
        <integration.version>v4.5.1</integration.version>
        <camel.version>4.1.0</camel.version>
        <specifications.generator.version>v2.0.2</specifications.generator.version>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
        <payhub-contract.version>v1.68.1</payhub-contract.version>
        <app.ext.version>v2.3.1</app.ext.version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>application</module>
        <module>contract</module>
        <module>domain</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>company.project.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>application</artifactId>
                <version>${integration.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>20231013</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>company.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>payhub-contract</artifactId>
            <version>${payhub-contract.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>company.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>specifications-generator</artifactId>
            <version>${specifications.generator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.kaczmarzyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>specification-arg-resolver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.prowide</groupId>
            <artifactId>pw-swift-integrator</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured-common</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-features-logging</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>company.project.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>application</artifactId>
            <version>${integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>company.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-app-ext</artifactId>
            <version>${app.ext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jms-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>aqapi</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0.0-jakarta</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ons</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.i18n</groupId>
            <artifactId>orai18n</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-groovy-templates</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>company.recipes.webSecUtils</groupId>
            <artifactId>web-authorization</artifactId>
            <version>v2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <release>${java.version}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*Mapper*.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*Secured*.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*SOAP*.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*DateConversion*.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/dto/</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/esb/</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/model/</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/shared/</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*XmlFormatter.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*Configuration.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*Configurations.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*Resource.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*Security*.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*Application.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*Config.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*Result.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*Response.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*Request.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/properties/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*Exception*.*/</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/liquibase/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/resources/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/gcc/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/OutwardLocalPostingUseCaseImpl.*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPaths}</destFile>
                    <append>true</append>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-integration-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>report-integration</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-integration</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-integration</goal>
                        </goals>

                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>check-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>${jacoco.coverageRatio}</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>LINE</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>${jacoco.coverageRatio}</minimum>
                                        </limit>

                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>METHOD</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>${jacoco.coverageRatio}</minimum>
                                        </limit>

                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>CLASS</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>${jacoco.coverageRatio}</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>*IT</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-test-source</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/e2e/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-test-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/e2e/resources</directory>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>**/folder-to-exclude/**</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <runOrder>projectbetical</runOrder>
                    <argLine>-Xverify:none -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1</argLine>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Xverify:none -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1</argLine>
                    <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classesDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <runOrder>projectbetical</runOrder>
                    <argLine>-Xverify:none -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1</argLine>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>integration-tests</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>integration-test</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>none</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                                </includes>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <id>integration-tests</id>
                        <reports>
                            <report>failsafe-report-only</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>


</project>


you have a multimodule project with three modules, but provided only the toplevel  pom - I would guess that you start the application in the "application" module, but your whole pom.xml looks a bit messy to me as you define so much dependencies and plugins in your top level pom. Also what Java version are you using? (The pom also defines "use the java version of the maven tool currently executed" - I never saw a definition as loose as that one.) With that big toplevel pom this could get tough to analyze.

I am using java 17

can you add the poms of your modules to the question please?

I do have the same issue. This is related to the new Jetty version 12.x Springboot 3.2.x comes with. When using Springboot 3.1.x the Jetty version switches to 11.x and the problem disappears.

I am having the same issue is there a defect for this?

What was the solution???

Well, not really a solution but a workaroud: I moved from Jetty to Netty and the problem was gone
